# Can't use JSON string from PHP in casperjs

Tags: javascript, php, json, casperjs

I cant set json in args to use it in casperjs script.

Im launching first casperjs script, it return object in php file and then i need to use it in another one.
im trying to make it like this:

```
$command = "$casperjs $script $arg0";
$result = shell_exec($command);
$json_data = json_decode($result, true);
//here im getting some data from json but dont change it
$arg1 = json_encode($json_data); // i ried take $result but have the same result
$command = "$casperjs $script2 $arg1";
$json_data = shell_exec($command);
```

And here i have error:

```
SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string
```

$result

```
{ "url": "bilko.com", "webPages": [ { "url": "bilko.com", "links": [ "/site-map", "/en/", "/biography", "/gallery", "/services", "/contacts", "/gallery/corporative", "/gallery/wedding", "/gallery/birthday", "/gallery/teambuilding" ], "content": "\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\n\t \n \n \n \n \n \n" } ], "menus": { "identifier": ".menu", "items": [ [ { "text": "Биография", "url": "/biography" }, { "text": "Галерея", "url": "/gallery" }, { "text": "Услуги", "url": "/services" }, { "text": "Контакты", "url": "/contacts" } ] ] }, "top": { "content": "/images/topLogo.png", "identifier": "header" }, "footer": { "content": "Профессиональный ведущий\nНиколай Билько\n+7 925 025 33 27\n", "identifier": "footer" }, "socBtns": [ [ "https://vk.com/id23333446", "/images/socBtns/vk.png" ] ], "sitemap": [ "/biography", "/contacts", "/en/", "/gallery", "/gallery/birthday", "/gallery/corporative", "/gallery/teambuilding", "/gallery/wedding", "/services", "/site-map", null ] }
```

in script2 im trying to make

```
site = JSON.parse(system.args[4]);
```

Comment: So, what does `$result` contain?

Comment: Add the object to your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data to casperjs then write it to a file and pass the path to the casperjs script. You can then <kbd>[`read`](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/read.html)</kbd> the contents of the file:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var site = JSON.parse(fs.read(system.args[4]));
```

You can write the JSON string to a temporary file in the php script:

```
$tmp = tempnam(dirname(__FILE__), "tmp");
file_put_contents($tmp, json_encode($json_data));
$json_data = shell_exec("$casperjs $script2 $tmp");
unlink($tmp);
```

Possible failures might be:

- limit of argument length (something like 120 characters)
- you can't have spaces in `$arg1`
- your shell might try to interpret `""` inside of the JSON string, so enclose the whole string in `''`: `"$casperjs $script2 '$arg1'"`
- you also have non-ansi characters there that might break the call depending on the shell